# Derive generic method from generic method of non-generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a non-generic base class with a generic method I want to extend this method by adding some extra code while the rest of the method should remain the same by calling base.Method

here an example

```
public override List<T> MyMethod<T>()
{

// do some work in here
...
// 

return base.MyMethod<T>(); // **I get an error here saying that T must be a reference type**
}
```

Comment: You might want to specify the language as a tag; looks like C# but I'm not positive.

Comment: @pointy i added the c# tag due to the fact that the `override` keyword is there...

Comment: it is C#.net sorry, you guys are fast.

Comment: Since you are overriding the base class, How can you be sure that the `base.MyMethod` will return a `List<T>`?

Comment: Because signature of base.MyMethod says so. List<T> MyMethod<T>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried this and it compiles just fine:**

```
public class Base
{
    // Base method has a 'class' constraint
    public virtual List<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    // Override does not declare any constraints; constraints are inherited
    public override List<T> MyMethod<T>()
    {
        // base call works just fine
        return base.MyMethod<T>();
    }
}
```

Your error is not in the code you posted. It must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Timwi, my bad (Java roots) VIRTUAL was not specified on the base class method.

Comment: Now I have to figure out how to work around this limitation :(

Comment: @Ivan: Either make the base method virtual, or (if you can’t) give *your* method a different name (but the same generic type constraint).

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you have a class constraint on your base method. You just need to have the same constraint on the override

```
public override List<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class
```

Comment: Yes, there is a constraint, but I can't add my own because constraints are inherited.

Comment: @Ivan, you need to specify the same constraint on your override, constraints aren't implicitly inherited.

Comment: The compiler complains that constraints for override are inherited from the base method.

Comment: @Ivan you're right, I made a dotnetpad paste, not sure what you're doing wrong then. You may want to post your base class http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/pUDfkptUik-mI53hbemujQ#c-1,

Comment: I tagged as correct because if constraints are not specified in the base class'es method, then this way is the correct one to introduce them in the derived method. Thanks everyone for help! Much appreciated!
EDIT: the tag goes away, I guess I can mark only one answer as correct. Sorry. The other one is more correct :)

Comment: @Ivan: I’m afraid that’s untrue; you cannot introduce new generic type parameter constraints in a virtual method override.